# pass regex from a external file ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have 2 files. File 1 (main.log) is a text file with a bunch of text. File 2 (clean.log) is also a text file. I want to be able to detect the presence of text from file 2 in file 1 on a line by line basis. Here is what I have right now for my ruby script

```
  require 'rubygems'
  regexen=''
  file = 'main.log'
  replace_file = 'clean.log'
  logfile_du = File.open(file, mode='r')
  params_file = File.open(replace_file,mode='r')
  logfile_du.each {
  |line1|
  line1.chomp!
  params_file.each {
          |line|
          line.chomp!
          regexen = /^#{line}.*/

  print line1

  if line1 =~ /#{regexen}/
      print "match\n"
  else
    print "no_match\n"
  end
  }
  }
```

here is the main.log file

```
  #DoNotEditThisLine: UndoCommandFile 206.40.123.77 17.0b ERBS_NODE_MODEL_H_1_167_COMPLETE stopfile=/tmp/27006

  gs+

  crn ENodeBFunction=1,EUtranCellFDD=311480-936016-3
  acBarringForCsfb acBarringFactor=95,acBarringTime=64,acBarringForSpecialAC=false false false false false
  acBarringForEmergency false
  acBarringForMoData acBarringFactor=95,acBarringTime=64,acBarringForSpecialAC=false false false false false
  acBarringForMoSignalling acBarringFactor=95,acBarringTime=64,acBarringForSpecialAC=false false false false false
  acBarringInfoPresent true
```

Here is the clean.log file

```
acBarringForCsfb
acBarringForMoData
acBarringForMoSignalling
acBarringPresence
```

Current output that I am getting

```
 #DoNotEditThisLine: UndoCommandFile 206.40.123.77 17.0b 
 ERBS_NODE_MODEL_H_1_167_COMPLETE stopfile=/tmp/27006
 no_match
  #DoNotEditThisLine: UndoCommandFile 206.40.123.77 17.0b 
  ERBS_NODE_MODEL_H_1_167_COMPLETE stopfile=/tmp/27006
  no_match
  #DoNotEditThisLine: UndoCommandFile 206.40.123.77 17.0b 
  ERBS_NODE_MODEL_H_1_167_COMPLETE stopfile=/tmp/27006
  no_match
  #DoNotEditThisLine: UndoCommandFile 206.40.123.77 17.0b 
  ERBS_NODE_MODEL_H_1_167_COMPLETE stopfile=/tmp/27006
   no_match
```

Expected Output

```
    #DoNotEditThisLine: UndoCommandFile 206.40.123.77 17.0b ERBS_NODE_MODEL_H_1_167_COMPLETE stopfile=/tmp/27006
    no_match
    gs+
    no_match
    crn ENodeBFunction=1,EUtranCellFDD=311480-936016-3
    no_match
    acBarringForCsfb acBarringFactor=95,acBarringTime=64,acBarringForSpecialAC=false false false false false
    match
    acBarringForEmergency false
    no_match
    acBarringForMoData acBarringFactor=95,acBarringTime=64,acBarringForSpecialAC=false false false false false
    match
    acBarringForMoSignalling acBarringFactor=95,acBarringTime=64,acBarringForSpecialAC=false false false false false
    match
    acBarringInfoPresent true
    no_match
```

Can someone please advise what I am missing here.

Update - The code worked after I switch to using readlines method instead of each

```
    #!/usr/bin/env ruby


    require 'rubygems'

    regexen=''

    file = 'main.log'
    replace_file = 'clean.log'
    i=1
    File.readlines('main.log').each do |line1|

    print "#{i}\n"
    line1.chomp!
    File.readlines('clean.log').each do |line|

            line.chomp!
            regexen = /#{line}.*/


    if line1 =~ /#{regexen}/
        print "match\n"
      #  print line1
    else
      print "no_match\n"

    end
    end

    i=i+1
    end
```

Comment: What is the use-case here? `grep` can get you 90% of the way here without any custom code.

Comment: The _inner_ loop prints out the _outter_ loops line for as many inner lines there are. Also, don't you have to _rewind_ the inner loop's file position each pass of the outter loop ? You could fix that by moving the print to the outter loop, only printing the word match when there is a match, then break to the outter loop

Comment: Yeah, i think you are correct. how do I change position of the line iterator ? so that it starts at the next line instead of starting from the top each time.

Comment: The use case here is that I want to delete the matched lines. so first step is to detect match and then delete them.

Comment: @ssharma This is exactly what `grep`, `diff`, and similar tools are for. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

The code worked after I switch to using readlines method instead of each

```
   #!/usr/bin/env ruby


    require 'rubygems'

    regexen=''

    file = 'main.log'
    replace_file = 'clean.log'
    logfile_du = File.open(file, mode='r')

    params_file = File.open(replace_file,mode='r')
    i=1
    File.readlines('main.log').each do |line1|

    print "#{i}\n"
    line1.chomp!
    File.readlines('clean.log').each do |line|

            line.chomp!
            regexen = /#{line}.*/


    if line1 =~ /#{regexen}/
        print "match\n"
      #  print line1
    else
      print "no_match\n"

    end
    end

    i=i+1
    end
```